Can TerminateThread() terminate GetCurrentThread()?
The docs don't say whether the result of GetCurrentThread() is a valid argument to TerminateThread(), iow: whether a thread can cancel itself.
Can it? And if yes, does TerminateThread() then return at all?

Why do you need it for the current thead ? You could simply exit the thread function, which is also cleaner anyway. In any case TerminateThread should only be used as a last resort.

@wohlstad This is a class library whose Thread class has a terminate() method. As the library author, I don't control how users use it, but I need to be able to maintain the features of the underlying OS. pthread_cancel(pthread_self()) is ok, so I was merely wondering whether I need to support or reject self-termination.

"I was merely wondering whether I need to support or reject self-termination." - You MUST reject the idea of calling TerminateThread(). "As the library author, I don't control how users use it" - As a library author you have full agency over this aspect. A trivial example: If you don't provide a terminate() function in your public interface clients won't be calling into it. It is literally this simple. This isn't an incredibly wild design choice either: C++' std::thread and std::jthread do not provide a public interface to terminate the thread they control.

@MarcMutz-mmutz even if you for some reason you must support a terminate API (despite the comment above), you could still check if the thread you need to terminate is the current one, and if so - call ExitThread instead of TerminateThread which is much more brutal.

There is a big difference between pthread_cancel and TerminateThread. pthread_cancel implements cooperative cancellation meaning that it doesn't outright destroy the thread kernel object. The thread is even allowed to ignore the cancellation request from pthread_cancel.
Using TerminateThread though is akin to planting a bomb into your code. You might as well write if (rand() < 10) ExitProcess(EXCEPTION_INVALID_HANDLE); instead.

@AlexVeleshko Calling TerminateThread() is far, far worse than randomly terminating a process.

@IInspectable Well, it's the simplest didactic example.

@AlexVeleshko It isn't. ExitProcess() has well defined post conditions. TerminateThread() does not.

Yes, TerminateThread can terminate the current thread. The result of GetCurrentThread has THREAD_ALL_ACCESS rights, so that handle can be used too.
No, TerminateThread won't return in this case.
No, there is no reason to ever do this! Don't.

Windows started picking up the really big pieces of TerminateThread garbage on the sidewalk, but it’s still garbage on the sidewalk.

Note, though, that GetCurrentThread() returns a pseudo handle, not a real handle, which is distinctly different from the return value of CreateThread(). Either way, the caller has the THREAD_ALL_ACCESS access right. I'm just pointing this out since the OP is asking for one thing but then move ahead to explain that they're doing something else.

To answer your immediate question:
Since the docs do not prohibit to call TerminateThread from the current thread, I infer that using any thread handle is valid, including the current one.
In that case since the thread is terminated always before TerminateThread returns, it will never return to the caller.
But it seems to be bad idea to do so:

Calling TerminateThread should only be used a a last resort.
There are many caveats in the documentation link above.

It also shows this summary:

TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases.


There are much better ways to end the current thread in an orderly fashion:
(1) Return from the thread function - this is the best way.
(2) Call ExitThread API.
Note that the ExitThread documentation makes a distinction between C++ and C code:

ExitThread is the preferred method of exiting a thread in C code. However, in C++ code, the thread is exited before any destructors can be called or any other automatic cleanup can be performed. Therefore, in C++ code, you should return from your thread function.



Given the 2 points above I cannot see a scenario where you would want to call TerminateThread for the current thread.
A final note
In reference to your comment about a library that might have to support a terminate thread API:
As mentioned in a comment, you should prefer not to support a terminate API at all (just as an example the C++ std::thread does not support it).
If you must support it - you could still check if the thread you need to terminate is the current one, and if so - call ExitThread (mentioned above) instead of TerminateThread which is much more brutal.

Thanks, but I don't need to be lectured about the validity of the question. This is not an answer to my question, I suggest to use comments instead, next time.

@MarcMutz-mmutz I was not trying to lecture you. Your question did not contain the context for your request and so I thought that explaining the alternative might be helpful. I still believe it contains information relevant to the question as posted.

fair enough, but I already linked to the docs of the function, and asked for the one aspect the docs don't answer. This answer merely repeats what the linked docs already say. That'd be ok ... if it also answered the actual question.

@MarcMutz-mmutz I added an actual answer, and also some info regarding the usage in a threads library that you mentioned in a comment. Again I want to emphasise that lecturing you want not my intention at all.

@MarcMutz-mmutz You're failing to comprehend fundamentals here. Interfaces are specified in terms of preconditions and postconditions. The callee guarantees that the specified postconditions hold as long as the preconditions are met. This is a proven scheme that allows clients to pass control to foreign code and still maintain local invariants. The issue is that TerminateThread() HAS NO SPECIFIED POSTCONDITIONS. You call it and the process owning the target thread is instantly in an unspecified state. It's inconclusive to ask about guarantees when the call contract provides none.
